# Find $i^{\text{th}}k-\text{combination}$ in lexicographic order

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to obtain the $i^{\text{th}}k-\text{combination}$ in lexicographic order.

For instance, for $comb(10,5)$:

- $i=0: [0,1,2,3,4]$
- $i=1: [0,1,2,3,5]$
- $i=2: [0,1,2,3,6]$
- $\dots$
- $i=10: [0,1,2,4,8]$

I have read about an efficient mapping ([combinadic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system)) but it does not hold this property.

For instance, for $i=10$ would give $[1,2,3,4,6]$ and for $i=11$ would give $[0,1,2,5,6]$.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order in the tuples. The combinatorial number system is ordered with respect to the lexicographical order with the higher numbers having the higher weight.